# Find the Kth smallest element

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone explain what I do wrong? I want to find k-th smallest element but something goes wrong)

Example: I have unsorted array
int[] uA = {**2, 9, 4, 13, 11, 7, 8**};
I take "9" as a pivot element and after first iteration of partiting(quick sort) I will have this array {2, 8, 4, 7, 11, 13, 9}. Where middle pointer will be show at "11". And what does it mean at all? Not all elements right to 11 bigger than 11. And 11 is not at "the right place" at all. But, for example, I want to return 5th smallest element(11).

Comment: At the end of the partitioning, you need to swap the pivot into the right place. That would here lead to `{ 2, 8, 4, 7, 9, 13, 11 }`.

Comment: Are you sure about it? I think that "9" at the right place right now(for first iteration). I swaped "9" with "8" and moved pointers l++ and r--. You know) As a result I've got {2, **8**, 4, 7, 11, 13, **9**}. So I splitted my array into {2, 8, 4, 7} and {11, 13, 9}. And because (middle pointer position == 5th) element I should take "11". But it's wrong!

Comment: The point of the partitioning is to have an arrangement `[smaller than pivot] pivot [larger than pivot]` (where one of smaller resp. larger contains the equals), so that you can recur on the shorter parts of the array (for finding the k-th smallest element, on one of the shorter parts).

Comment: I understand this, but what's wrong with my arrangenent? I made correct "like quick sort" first iteration and got pivot at the end of array. I don't understand your "you need to swap the pivot into the right place".

Answer (score 1):

The pivot is not at the right place, you should put the pivot to the right place at the end of the partitioning to find out the position of the pivot. (You really do not need to care about the middle element) Then you can use this information to calculate the Kth smallest element. Let's say the pivot is at x th index at the end of partitioning;

```
K = x =>  pivot is the right answer
K < x =>  the answer is in the left partition, search left partition  
K > x =>  the answer is in the right partition, search right partition
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand this "you should ***put the pivot to the right place*** at the end of the partitioning". How to determine "the right place"? We already compared the pivot element with others and put it at the end, right? And after that my program doesn't remember pivot's position, but my program knows it's value.

Comment: As I understand, you want to use the partitioning part of quicksort to get the Kth smallest element. In quick sort, you do not put the pivot to the end of the list, you put the pivot to the position where all the lesser elements are on the left and all the greater elements are on the right side of the pivot. [lesserElements] < pivot < [greaterElemeents]

Comment: I use this code for the partitioning part `int pivot = uA[1];
        int l = start;
        int r = end;

        while (l <= r){
            while (uA[l] < pivot) l++;
            while (uA[r] > pivot) r--;

            if (l <= r){
                int tmp = uA[l];
                uA[l] = uA[r];
                uA[r] = tmp;
                l++;
                r--;
            }
        }`

Comment: Just swaping two elements who not at the right place. In my array {2, 9, 4, 13, 11, 7, 8} this are "9" and "8" and pivot goes to the end of array

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in my code: after swapping of two elements in a partitioning part I moved pointers(left++, right--) like in a quick sort, but should'n.

*Thank you guys for yours attenthion!*